# Automatically populated Modified by table column - Access 2013

Tags: ms-access

I am creating an Access DB, but I would like it to include a modified by column in the table data.  Is there a way to have this automatically populated on modification?
Thanks 
Luke

Comment: Are you using a form to update records? Update to what value? The windows login name, or something else?

Comment: Hi Wayne, Thanks for the response.  I am using a form to update the table info.  It would be preferrable to get the Windows User ID.   
I tried using this:  
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
Me!ModifiedBy = Environ("username") ' this is the NT loginID
End Sub but it didn't work.  I just get a #Name? in the ModifiedBy field

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to put line breaks in

Comment: Do you have 'ModifiedBy' as a control on your form? If not, then you need to add it (you can hide it if you don't want it to show.  Also, I suggest syntax = Me.ModifiedBy rather than Me!ModifiedBy (yes, it will work with '!', and I know it's the Form because of 'Me', but ...)

Comment: I have ModifiedBy as a hidden text box.  The script I am running is running off the form though, not off the box.  I don't know if that makes a difference.  Thanks for your help.  I'll update the ! now.

Comment: 1. Make sure your query for the form's recordsource includes the field name 'ModifiedBy'; 2. Make sure the textbox 'Control Source' is set to 'ModifiedBy'

Comment: Also, FYI since the code is in the 'Insert' event, it will only save the value for NEW records. You should do the same code in the 'Before_Update' event.